# Why CSS .addClass is not applying proper style per specificity?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, addclass, css-specificity

I understand the concept of css specificity.
Here is my situation:

I have a style for class called "success". This simply makes colors green...etc.
Now I have 2 separate css files that defines .success (they define a different style).
Let's call these Site.css and Page.css.

The class in Site.css is simply:

```
.success { color: green; }
```

The class in Page.css is more specified:

```
#MainRegion div .resultPanel .success { background-color: green; }
```

Now in javascript (using jquery), I add a class like so:

```
$("#MainRegion div .resultPanel").addClass("success");
```

Now, when I inspect this using a browser-debugger (F12), I can see that the Site.css style was applied (rather than the Page.css). I thought the class defined in Page.css has more specificity thus it should be the one that is called. Am I missing something about my understanding of how css specificity works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing something. This line of code

```
$("#MainRegion div .resultPanel").addClass("success");
```

returns

```
#MainRegion div .resultPanel.success

<div class="resultPanel success"></div>
```

and not

```
#MainRegion div .resultPanel .success

<div class="resultPanel">
    <div class="success"></div>
</div>
```

So depending on what you want, you can change your css or the js to target the correct element

if your css is

```
#MainRegion div .resultPanel.success { background-color: green; }
```

then your js will work as expected

Answer (score 0):

Honestly you should probably create a different class for success on one of your style sheets. If i am understanding correctly you are going to have a green BG with green font color. Both of the style sheets should work together since you are only defining different things for both calls but that isn't a best practice.

Comment: oh yea, I am sure OP will notice that issue when the code starts working